# Elastic Search Aggregation Query of multiple levels optimization

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

Need an better way or optimized query to retrieve the statuses of each level.

we are trying to get the aggregation data of IoT devices status from a huge volume stored in the ES. The data in the storage will be like following

```
{
"deviceType":"temperature",
"deviceName":"sensor1",
"serviceName":"HomeService",
"serviceCatagory":"Home Automation",
"warning":true,
"communicationType":"http",
"createdDate":"",
"location":"",
"poc":"",
"aPoc":""
}
```

and fields will be added according to the type of device. for each status a document will be inserted into the DB.

Using this data we are applying aggregation query on it to find the count of each status for each devicetype or device or serviceName or serviceCategory or location etc..

The sample aggregation query we are hitting the DB is,

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "hour_value": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "hour"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "devicetype": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "deviceType",
            "size": 1000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "deviceName",
              "size": 1000
            },
            "aggs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "serviceName",
                "size": 1000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "serviceCatogery",
                  "size": 1000
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "location",
                    "size": 1000
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "warning_count": {
                      "value_count": {
                        "field": "warning"
                      }
                    },
                    "trip_count": {
                      "value_count": {
                        "field": "trip"
                      }
                    },
                    "running_count": {
                      "value_count": {
                        "field": "running"
                      }
                    },
                    "stopped_count": {
                      "value_count": {
                        "field": "stopped"
                      }
                    },
                    "offline_count": {
                      "value_count": {
                        "field": "offline"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The size specified in the query will be even more for some days.

But the above query is taking too much time (almost 15 min and some time it was hanging) to get the data from the DB.
The volume we are aggregating is almost 12 GB per hour and we are trying to hit this query for each hour.

Any help with the idea or query would be too helpful.

Comment: What is the size of index? How many shards in the index? Why do you need such a deep level of aggregations nesting? Is is not possible to filter data and then apply aggregations? For e.g. filter by device type and the apply aggregation.

Comment: Size as i already specified 12 GB for each hour.For each month one index will be created and accordingly data stored in it with the  replication as 2 and shards are 5. we are trying to store this aggregated data into one more new index (contains devicetype, devicename, service, category and their respective statuses count in a single document for that perticular hour) so that it is easy to access with the less volume instead of hitting the huge volume again and again (for UI purpose). once it is aggregated and stores in new index we will apply the filters on top of it (it will take less time).